# Postgres: Range Lookup with Auto increment

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table: table1

```
begin | value | end
---------------------
  1   |   3   | 10
  1   |   5   | 10
  1   |   2   | 10
  1   |   7   | 10
 11   |   19  | 20
 11   |   16  | 20
 11   |  14   | 20
```

I am looking for the following output:

```
begin | value | end | case
-----------------------------
  1   |   3   | 10  |  1
  1   |   5   | 10  |  1
  1   |   2   | 10  |  1
  1   |   7   | 10  |  1
 11   |  19   | 20  |  2
 11   |  16   | 20  |  2
 11   |  14   | 20  |  2
```

I want to assign a unique number for numbers falling within a particular range but I am unable to find my way around it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not just `SELECT *,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY "begin") AS "case"
FROM data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.  This is a gap and islands problem.  You can identify where islands start by checking that there are no other rows that overlap with them.  For that, you can use a cumulative max.

This gets you close:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) filter where (prev_end < start) over (order by start) as grp
from (select t.*,
             max(end) over (order by start range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_end
      from t
     ) t;
```

However, the ties in the data mean that this has gaps.  So, one more level:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by grp) as sequential_grp
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where prev_end < start) over (order by start) as grp   
      from (select t.*,
                   max(end) over (order by start range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_end
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=29f74e6ed1a29ca45168a807d81eb45e) is a db<>fiddle -- with the column names changed, because names like `begin` and `end` are SQL keywords and hence a bad idea for column names.